# What is the difference between transform.Rotate methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

What is the actual difference between the 2 available [transform.Rotate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) method overloads?

One version uses floats for its parameters, while another uses a Vector3 that appears to use the same parameters.

Is there a preferred/best practice/better performing option between the two? The documentation does not really say one way or the other.

```
transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor, 0));
transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor, 0);
```

Comment: Use whichever one is most convenient to the current code. Undoubtedly one calls the other, but we are deliberately not told which way that works because it is an internal implementation detail irrelevant to the proper functioning of the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. I suggest picking the one that makes the code easiest to read: if you have a vector that you can use (e.g. angular velocity), use that vector; if you have a float for each axis (e.g. mouse movement), use the one that accepts three floats. It's a matter of what will be the most readable to you when you come back to that code trying to fix some bug.

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for. In the above sample the context was within mouse movement and object rotation (as you probably figured out given the arguments specified), and the reasons for using one versus the other make total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both the rotate methods are almost same yet very different:

The Method

```
public void Rotate(float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle);
```

takes in three 'Angles' and rotate the object in the direction of the provided angles.

On the contrary the method

```
public void Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle);
```

takes a vector defining the axis of rotation and a float defining the angle (how much you want to rotate it?). For example, If you set the `axis` to `new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);` and set the `angle` to `15f`, the rotate method will rotate the object to 15 degrees along z-axis only. This rotate method will only check which axis in the `axis` parameter has a value greater than 0 and rotate the object around that axis only.

Comment: Also if you set the `axis` param to `new Vector3(0, 0, 3)`, this rotate method will still consider that the user wants to rotate around z-axis and will not use `3f` as rotation multiplier.

Comment: The second `Rotate` method you picked was the wrong one: asker is using `public void Rotate(Vector3 eulerAngles)`, not axis-angle.